# Quadrature sensor sinus signal to distance value

Tags: c, algorithm, math, methods, sensors

From a sensor I have 4 signals in quadrature. Two signals are analog and two are digital. The signals represent the position of a pickup sensor, se figure. The signals are:

- A-Analog
- B-Analog
- A-Digital
- B-Digital

The analog signals are phase shifted by 90 degrees. The digital signal is produced by a zero crossing detector. One period of the analog signal represent 2 mm of movement of the sensor.

I can catch the minimum and maximum value of the analog signal via an ADC (10 bit) when I have a transition of the digital signal. I can also use the phase relations of the digital signals to detect if we are moving in a positive or negative direction. I can easily also measure the distance by detecting the transitions of the digital signals with a resolution of 1 mm.

But what is the **best** algorithm/method to get the fractional part of the distance based on the current values of the analog signals? I want to do that with maximal dynamic resolution by combining the A and B analog signal.

Figure: [image: http://www.spectron.us/SM6FIE//Images/ScreenCut1.JPG]
<sub>(source: [spectron.us](http://www.spectron.us/SM6FIE//Images/ScreenCut1.JPG))</sub>

Comment: “From a sensor I have for signals” should be: “From a sensor I have four signals…”

Comment: Without thinking about it too much, I'd say that a [Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/integrated1/venema_kalman_encoders.pdf) might give you a good estimate for the intermediate positions. But I'd have to think about it to say exactly how it would apply.  Also, it will depend on what you assume about the dynamics of the motion: can it be ludicrously quick (impossible?), or is the motion highly constrained?

Comment: Thanks Peter. The movement is rather slow, up to max 75 mm per second. I have an ADC value about every 2 mS for each analog value (A/B). So the resolution at max speed is: 0.15 mm. However mostly the speed is more moderate and in the order of 0.1 to 5 mm per second. @Peter K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your analog signals are roughly sinusoidal then you can think of them as the sine and cosine of the phase angle (one full 2mm travel would be 2 * pi radians of phase).  In C (and other languages) you can use the [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function to convert from your analog signals to phase angle.  In pseudo code you would have:

```
fractional_distance = atan2(analog-A, analog-B) * 2 mm / 2 pi radians
```

If your signals are not actually sinusoidal then this will still work, it will just introduce distortions in your fractional distance.